# How to fix typescript error with next.js?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

How can I fix this error? I use next.js with typescript and I didn't set webpack.

I trid to install @zeit/next-typescript and fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin.

This error happend because of my settings?

```
ERROR in undefined(undefined,undefined):
TS2318: Cannot find global type 'BigInt'.
```

Please give me advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Typescript are you on? I don't use `next.js` but this seems to be an issue with the fact that `BigInt` is still not implemented in many environments. `BigInt` support in Typescript only recently landed in [version 3.2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-2.html). If you are not on that version I would recommend trying to upgrade as a first step.

Comment: Thank you. I did it